# Method not working with SFType in a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I have a small class that helps me pull salesforceobject dataframes and columns.  I am having an issue with the SFType from the simple_salesforce package.  I am trying to retrieve the column headers from the dataframe of a certain salesforce object.  Here is a snippet of my class:

```
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce
from simple_salesforce import SFType
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class SfData:
    def __init__(self,user,pw,token,obj):
        self.user = user
        self.pw = pw
        self.token = token
        self.sf = Salesforce(username = self.user,password = self.pw, security_token=self.token)
        self.obj = obj

    def retrieve_columns(self):
        df = SFType(self.obj, self.sf.session_id, self.sf.sf_instance)
        col_names = [x['name'] for x in self.sf.df.describe()['fields']]
        return col_names
```

After calling the class I get the following error when I call the method:

```
test.SfData(myuser,mypw,mytoken,"Account")
test.retrieve_columns()

Resource df Not Found. Response content: [{'errorCode': 'NOT_FOUND', 'message': 'The requested resource does not exist'}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't need use my credentials to call the method "describe", instead:

```
df = SFType(self.obj, self.sf.session_id, self.sf.sf_instance)
data = df.describe()
columns = [x['name'] for x in data['fields']]
return columns
```